# What does a blue bar indicated in xUnit.net Test Runner?

Tags: xunit.net, test-runner

I know about green and red, but what is the meaning of the blue/violet seen below?

[image]

This happened after running the `Sync` test, then running it again.
The `Total tests:2, Failures: 1, Skipped: 0` status bar is rather strange, by the way.